# How to get the same output signal but with an increased capacitive load?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, capacitance, cmos, load

I'm designing a CMOS circuit of a VCO and it works perfectly fine when tested independently. Now when I cascade an other block like a divider to it, the output isn't the same as before. Rather its frequency and amplitude have fallen down. I suspect it's because of the gate capacitances of the transistors in the divider.
Are there any modifications or additions which I can make to achieve the same output as before?

Comment: $$\style{color:RED;}{B-U-F-F-E-R}$$

Comment: Yeah I did try using a buffer in between the two, but I was only able to achieve the desired output after the VCO. The signal after the output of the buffer and input to the divider is still not able to achieve full swing.

Comment: For full swing, you may need a rail-to-rail opamp for your buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Well looks like I solved it on my own.
I used progressively increasing sized (W/L ratio)  inverters of even numbers which acted as a buffer in between the VCO and divider.
The full swing at the last stage was achieved because of the higher W/L ratio of the inverter at the last stage.